# Android Google Analytics: Does setAppOptOut() disable EasyTracker?

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics

In my Android app, I'm using both `Tracker` and `EasyTracker`.

`Tracker` instance is created using a `GoogleAnalytics` instance,

```
mTracker = mGa.getTracker(GA_PROPERTY_ID);
```

But `EasyTracker` does not use `GoogleAnalytics` for instantiation,

```
EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
```

So when I opt out of analytics using `GoogleAnalytics`,

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setAppOptOut(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false));
```

Will this also disable the tracking done by `EasyTracker`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `appOptOut` property enables or disables all Google Analytics tracking activity, whether it is done via `EasyTracker` or `Tracker`.

This is because `EasyTracker` uses the `GoogleAnalytics` singleton to do initialization behind the scenes.

As such, the `GoogleAnalytics` singleton manages state for all of your trackers, whether `Tracker` or `EasyTracker`, and its properties and configuration options apply to both kinds of trackers.